# Get twitter video mp4 url

Tags: php, video, twitter

Question I am working with twitter API now and when post includes video. Twitter returns only thumbnails urls and not main video file url. Twitter returns such JSON:

```
["media_url"]=> string(86) "http://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/../pu/img/p1R5iC_7fN-lqNuK.jpg" 
["media_url_https"]=> string(87) "https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/.../pu/img/p1R5iC_7fN-lqNuK.jpg" 
["url"]=> string(22) "http://t.co/UViL9KykF*" 
["expanded_url"]=> string(63) "http://twitter.com/.../status/..../video/1"
```

And first two is jpgs, and other urls redirect straight to post.
As I am using php to get all information, for vine.co there was such code:

```
$dom = new DomFinder($media_url);
$video_cell = $dom->find("//meta[@property='twitter:player:stream']", 'content');
```

But twitter doesn't have such meta tags in  and I can't find a way to access video file.
Maybe someone know how to get mp4 url?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twitter staff has stated [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-video-support-in-rest-and-streaming-api/31258/19) that they won't be supporting fetching videos using search. You will have to fetch videos with an other call to the API.

Let's say you have a tweet fetched using search/tweets saved in **$tweet**

```
// Check if tweet has media
if (!empty($tweet->entities->media)) {
    $searchArray = array(
        "id" => $tweet->id, // id of the tweet we just fetched
        "include_entities" => true // tells twitter API to return videos and stuff
    );

    // Get extended_entities
    $extendedEntities = $connection->get("statuses/show", $searchArray);
    foreach($extendedEntities->extended_entities->media as $media){
        var_dump($media->video_info->variants);
    }
}
```

**Example result**

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[265]
      public 'bitrate' => int 832000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/webm' (length=10)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/480x480/gj_fzyk29R9dMPBY.webm' (length=92)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[266]
      public 'bitrate' => int 832000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/480x480/gj_fzyk29R9dMPBY.mp4' (length=91)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[267]
      public 'bitrate' => int 1280000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/720x720/S7F4BF2wKR2txCpA.mp4' (length=91)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[268]
      public 'content_type' => string 'application/dash+xml' (length=20)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/pl/udxtIM8FytsAE4HQ.mpd' (length=82)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[269]
      public 'bitrate' => int 320000
      public 'content_type' => string 'video/mp4' (length=9)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/vid/240x240/v5jqpUNnkaeuVZbx.mp4' (length=91)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[270]
      public 'content_type' => string 'application/x-mpegURL' (length=21)
      public 'url' => string 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560049056895209473/pu/pl/udxtIM8FytsAE4HQ.m3u8' (length=83)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the option `tweet_mode:'extended'` to get the **extended_entities** object in the response.
This path in the response will have video urls : `extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants`

Example:

```
[
  {
    content_type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  },
  {
    bitrate: 832000,
    content_type: 'video/mp4',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  },
  {
    bitrate: 256000,
    content_type: 'video/mp4',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  }
]
```