# Get video from tweet using Twitter API

Tags: video, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to import a video from a given tweet.  However, when I use the `statuses/show` endpoint, it doesn't return any extended entity for the video as it would an image, but instead returns a URL entity linking to some video container embed with a video player containing an obscure link to the video.

Here is an example:

I am trying to import the tweet at `https://twitter.com/NHL/status/633987786018717696`

Using the Twitter API's `statuses/show` endpoint and the tweet id, I get this response:

```
{
  "created_at": "Wed Aug 19 13:04:01 +0000 2015",
  "id": 633987786018717700,
  "id_str": "633987786018717696",
  "text": "The offseason has us missing all of our fans, even the wacky ones... especially the wacky ones. #IsItOctoberYet?\nhttps :/ /t . co/v4UGDQpa61",
  "source": "<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>",
  "truncated": false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "user":  {
    "id": 50004938,
    "id_str": "50004938",
    "name": "NHL",
    "screen_name": "NHL",
    "location": "30 cities across U.S. & Canada",
    "description": "The official source of everything you need and want to know from the National Hockey League. Read before tweeting us: http : / /t . co/JlyVXSpqMn",
    "url": "http : / /t . co/VI8RlwuVr9",
    "entities":  {
      "url":  {
        "urls":  [
           {
            "url": "http : / /t . co/VI8RlwuVr9",
            "expanded_url": "http://www.NHL.com",
            "display_url": "NHL.com",
            "indices":  [
              0,
              22
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "description":  {
        "urls":  [
           {
            "url": "http : / / t . co/JlyVXSpqMn",
            "expanded_url": "http://nhl.com/socialmediapolicy",
            "display_url": "nhl.com/socialmediapol…",
            "indices":  [
              118,
              140
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "protected": false,
    "followers_count": 4130811,
    "friends_count": 2646,
    "listed_count": 18479,
    "created_at": "Tue Jun 23 15:24:18 +0000 2009",
    "favourites_count": 909,
    "utc_offset": -14400,
    "time_zone": "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "verified": true,
    "statuses_count": 87436,
    "lang": "en",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "is_translation_enabled": true,
    "profile_background_color": "000000",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000139631457/fd-xWa9G.jpeg",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000139631457/fd-xWa9G.jpeg",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/534776558238437376/yxrm83O7_normal.jpeg",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/534776558238437376/yxrm83O7_normal.jpeg",
    "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/50004938/1435502670",
    "profile_link_color": "040CDE",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "2E2E2E",
    "profile_text_color": "0F5A80",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "has_extended_profile": false,
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": true,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "notifications": false
  },
  "geo": null,
  "coordinates": null,
  "place": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "retweet_count": 865,
  "favorite_count": 1342,
  "entities":  {
    "hashtags":  [
       {
        "text": "IsItOctoberYet",
        "indices":  [
          96,
          111
        ]
      }
    ],
    "symbols":  [],
    "user_mentions":  [],
    "urls":  [
       {
        "url": "https : / /t . co/v4UGDQpa61",
        "expanded_url": "https://amp.twimg.com/v/2a0210d1-4d39-4665-a749-ea34f8efef08",
        "display_url": "amp.twimg.com/v/2a0210d1-4d3…",
        "indices":  [
          113,
          136
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
      "favorited": false,
      "retweeted": false,
      "possibly_sensitive": false,
      "possibly_sensitive_appealable": false,
      "lang": "en"
    }
```

Upon following the URL, the source of the video tag is `https://amp.twimg.com/amplify-web-player/prod/source.html?vmap_url=https%3A%2F%2Famp.twimg.com%2Fprod%2Fmultibr_v_1%2Fvmap%2F2015%2F08%2F20%2F13%2F609fc2af-1d06-4894-80be-1c231f97557a%2Fa69baa90-58de-4d1d-b2dc-2c3ef1ab9b35.vmap&duration=91.958&image_src=https%3A%2F%2Famp.twimg.com%2Fprod%2Fdefault%2F2015%2F08%2F20%2F13%2Fe8f0b317-ba48-4cec-bf2c-da4598e2b46b_poster-67227.jpg&content_id=609fc2af-1d06-4894-80be-1c231f97557a&page=amplify_card`

How do I extract this video file from the tweet if they do not supply an external_entity for it?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MingalevME No, once I found out it wasn't as straightforward, I moved on to something else

Comment: @terpak, you can check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32451450/4092887) or test this URL request: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=<TWEET_URL>&include_entities=true`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 13):

lIn Twitter API V1 the videos are stored in the extended_entities object. There could be multiple sources depending on bitrate. This is how to retrieve the one with the highest bitrate:

```js
var bitrate = 0;
var hq_video_url;
for (var j=0; j<tweet.extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants.length; j++) {
    if (tweet.extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants[j].bitrate) {
        if (tweet.extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants[j].bitrate > bitrate) {
            bitrate = tweet.extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants[j].bitrate;
            hq_video_url = tweet.extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants[j].url;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update for Twitter / X API V2**

In V2 of the API the response structure has changed slightly:

```
let media_url = includes[i].preview_image_url;
let bit_rate = 0;
for (var j=0; j<includes[i].variants.length; j++) {
    if (includes[i].variants[j].bit_rate > bit_rate) {
        let video_url = includes[i].variants[j].url;
        bit_rate = includes[i].variants[j].bit_rate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the video URL is only available on API V1.

Answer (score 6):

**Workaround for GIFs here!**

In Twitter API V2, it is not possible to fetch GIF and video URLs currently. I know it is too silly. But one workaround is to fetch the preview image of the content and construct the media URL by hand.

Let's say we want to get GIF URL of the following tweet via V2 API: https://twitter.com/FloodSocial/status/870042717589340160

When we fetch the tweet with the following URL
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/870042717589340160?tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,created_at,entities,id,text&media.fields=preview_image_url,url&expansions=attachments.media_keys (with your bearer token of course), you will see that the response includes a `preview_image_url` with https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/DBMDLy_U0AAqUWP.jpg

So here we can extract the `DBMDLy_U0AAqUWP` part from the URL, and construct the real GIF URL manually where it should be https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DBMDLy_U0AAqUWP.mp4

There you go. Only you need to write the extractor function.

Comment: It doesn't work now. Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

When using `statuses/show` endpoint , add this option  `tweet_mode:'extended'` to get the **extended_entities** object.
This path in the response will have video urls : `extended_entities.media[0].video_info.variants`
Example:

```
[
  {
    content_type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  },
  {
    bitrate: 832000,
    content_type: 'video/mp4',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  },
  {
    bitrate: 256000,
    content_type: 'video/mp4',
    url: 'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1358226.........'
  }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, depending on what platform you're using...

1. Connect to the URL directly
2. Consume the binary video data
3. Pump the binary data (e.g., a byte stream) through some widget that will display it.

The specifics on how to do this will vary greatly based on what platform & language(s) you are using.

Comment: I'm trying to make twitter videos downloadable through a browser extension. How do I pull streaming (.ts files) video binary data out of blob url (the video tags have blob URL as their `src`), and make the video downloadable? I saw a service for downloading video called https://twdown.net/. they are able to somehow get the `.mp4` path to the whole video file. How could one do that? Do you have a hint that could put me in right direction to find out anything? I'm stuck