# Play video from url which have no any extension in twitter response?

Tags: android, twitter, webview, android-videoview

I want to play video in videoview from `Twitter` response. But there is no extension(like .mp4) in url. I have get null video_info object from response where i use fabric for that.

So how to play video from that url or any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like it is a Twitter video, right? You need to get the final .mp4 Uri.

You should start over the [Twitter API](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-video-support-in-rest-and-streaming-api/31258) or, you can check this php example: [Get twitter video mp4 url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633063/get-twitter-video-mp4-url)

You would need to implement that over JAVA with [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) (for example)

Comment: i have must implement using fabric.and in response of timeline i got this type of url

Comment: Well... check the json response over: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-video-support-in-rest-and-streaming-api/31258 you have a "video_info" object and "variants". Over there: "url" is the one you need. Looks like this: https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/560070131976392705/pu/vid/1280x720\/c4E56sl91ZB7cpYi.mp4

Comment: main problem is media object return null in case of video type.

Comment: I've never use Fabric... don't know if you can get the media object. Twitter4j have full access to Twitter API

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a tweet with a video:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-video

Check `Customize video display` options.